# How to Return <div> in WordPress Function php file?

Tags: php

The code is:

```
function my_custom_function( $html, $content ) {


$html .=  get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);

return $html;
}



$priority = 10;

add_filter( 'tps_the_content_after', 'my_custom_function', $priority, 2 );
```

If my content is "`this is my content`", then the code return  "`this is my content`"

I want to add `<div>` before the content, but I don't know how to write the code,
it should return like this

```
"<div class="post">this is my content</div>"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your function should look something like this

```
function my_custom_function( $html, $content ) { 

$html .=  get_post_field('post_content', $post_id); 

$html = "<div class='post'>" . $html . "</div>"; 

return $html; 
}
```

Comment: $html .=  '<div class="post">';
$html .=  get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
$html .=  '</div>';